# Color Chart Rosetta Stone

Tags: colour

After discovering disparities between LEGO color names and families and 3rd party sites, I attempted to compile a sort of Rosetta Stone for the colors. Certain this is not complete but I believe a good start. Hope it helps. https://lego.pandorasdigitalbox.com/lego_color_rosetta.php

Any construtive ideas on how to improve it, or simple help completing it would be greatly appreciated.  Any suggestions or experiences you’d like to share would be welcomed too.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for putting this together. Unfortunately this type of post doesn’t really fit this site - a Q&A site - and I have voted to close this question.

Comment: My apologies for the mix up, but thank you for the help and information.

Comment: Hmm. It's unfortunate that this doesn't fit with the format. I think the link is super helpful, and I'm glad to have it. I wish @Ktulu9876 had enough reputation to ask and answer their own question.

Comment: If the link is helpful then it was all worth it. As more colors can be paired up updates will just happen. Thank you again and glad you enjoy the link.

Comment: @KurtisBeavers - you could create a question, and then Ktulu9876 could answer it, refering back to his site (and clearly state that this is his own site as a disclaimer - otherwise the answer might get flagged as spam). Something like “There are many different names for the same colors on various Lego fan sites, is there somewhere where you can look these up?”

Comment: Why don't we just get creative by slightly editing the cool post?  We just have to tack a question in there and we're good. Hmm.... So, what's a good question to answer?  Oh! Oh! I know!...

Comment: @KurtisBeavers Unless I'm missing something, you can always answer your own question, just maybe not an instant self-answer.

Comment: You should have added Brickowls color names also.. and i cant get that link to work about 99% of the time i clock on it.

Comment: As @AlexanderO'Mara states, this site is a little different from typical forums and the like elsewhere - we're based around Questions and Answers - if Ktulu9876 can post an answer along the lines of "I've created a Colour Rosetta here, it includes details from ..." (so that it's more than just a link answer), we can rework this into an actual question.

Comment: @NoobTheory, it seems as though you are looking for a way to associate all the various names of colors from many different sources. I may have an answer for you in the form of a chart that might help you with this. It is not from any of the various LEGO sites and represents work compiled on my own. I hope this helps and answers your question. https://lego.pandorasdigitalbox.com/lego_color_rosetta.php

Answer (score 3):

You can look for missing data in currently available lists:

[Old school Peeron](http://www.peeron.com/inv/colors) (no longer updated)

[Bricklink](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogColors.asp) list most of the brick colors available for sale.

[Rebrickable](https://rebrickable.com/colors/) has attempted to bring all colors in one place.

[Brickset](https://brickset.com/colours) has also some details.

[Mecabricks](https://www.mecabricks.com/docs/colour_chart.pdf) has one also (as PDF).

LDraw project has [such list](https://wiki.ldraw.org/index.php?title=User:Owen_Burgoyne/LDraw_Colour_Comparison_Chart).

It would also be good to define term "LEGO color". Is it for everything released by TLG or just the bricks with LEGO logo on them?

Last thing to note. People still keep finding genuine LEGO bricks made in officially not produced colors. So it is hard to mantain a *complete* list.

There are few people obsessed with LEGO colors, including Ryan Howerter. He has compiled a [list](http://ryanhowerter.net/colors.html) of colors and details around them. If you wish to see these parts and participate in discussion you can get over to Ryan's [Flickr picture gallery](https://www.flickr.com/photos/126975831@N07/).

Answer (score 2):

This color chart is from LEGO's Digital Draw program.

[image]
After doing a quick skim of it, I know you're missing the "Legacy" colors.  Whatever "Legacy" means here, I don't know.

- Colors read from Left to Right:

**METALLIC**

316 - Titanium Metallic

315 - Silver Metallic

309 - Metalized Silver

297 - Warm Gold

310 - Metalized Gold

**LEGACY**

298 - Cool Silver, Drum Lacq

179 - Silver Flip/Flop

002 - Grey

153 - Sand Red

025 - Earth Orange

139 - Copper

217 - Brown

105 - Bright Yellowish Orange

003 - Light Yellow

017 - Bright Bluish Green

195 - Royal Blue

011 - Pastel Blue

027 - Dark Grey

009 - Light Reddish Violet

147 - Metallic Sand Yellow

145 - Metallic Sand Blue

050 - Phosphorescent White

- Eventually, I would like to see real pictures of a brick maybe a
  (2x4) in each color.
- Oh, and please add the rendered pictures from LEGO's online
  PICK-A-BRICK.  My problem there was with 3 colors Dark Grey, Light
  Grey and White. After a while the grey shadows from the virtual
  bricks started playing tricks on my eyes making hard to tell which
  color I was buying. Very annoying.  I think the site has been like
  this since 2008. Eye torture.
- Great idea you got here!

Comment: Thank you very much, the addition of legacy colors might be helpful. My thinking was at the end of the day, all the pieces are from LEGO. So, I used them as the “gold standard”. Unfortunately they not only no longer have references to legacy colors/color families, most of the time they do not list all bricks in Pick-A-Brick, confirmed by LEGO through a phone call. So I piece nailed between LEGO/brickset. Going to “Missing Pieces” with a recent set number from brickset if necessary, hehe. But the addition of a piece image is a good idea. Thank you again and this project is far from done.

Comment: It is a nice idea to have a certain brick in all colors. However, this brick does not exist, as [a quick survey of the bricklink catalog](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/8972/what-lego-brick-is-available-in-the-most-colors/8974#8974) revealed. A DUPLO brick was available in most colors at that time! Maybe this has changed after about 18 months.

Comment: The DUPLO brick?! Crazy! Nice research on that post too.  Hmm... Well, I'm just imagining a scenario where I'm holding in my hand a brick I would describe as Dark Purple, and would like to buy more from LEGO online pick/brick.  I would never spontaneously think to search for "Medium Lilac".  So, maybe brick shape uniformity should come second, but what's more important to me is to have a real image of any colored brick to compare with what's in my hand, where I could visually verify that even though the duel describing words may be different, the color shades are the same.     .